# Zend framework: Meta property integration

Tags: facebook, zend-framework, metadata

I'm trying to add some meta (in the following format) to the head of my pages according to the page content:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="some content" />
```

Using the **headMeta()->appendName** like this:

```
$this->view->headMeta()->appendName('og:title', 'some content');
```

generates the following in the header:

```
<meta name="og:title" content="some content" />
```

Is there a way to make Zend generates **meta** with the **property** field?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like you need to create your own view-helper, extend the standard Zend Framework `HeadMeta` view helper, and implementing a method called `appendProperty()`, mimicking the behavior of `appendName()`.

Since the `appendName()` method seems to be handled in the `__call()` method, it looks like your extended class could simply copy the same `__call()` form the parent, but change the pattern used in the `preg_match()` from:

`'/^(?P<action>set|(pre|ap)pend|offsetSet)(?P<type>Name|HttpEquiv)$/'`

to

`'/^(?P<action>set|(pre|ap)pend|offsetSet)(?P<type>Name|HttpEquiv|Property)$/'`

[As a side note, it might be worthwhile to file an issue with the ZF tracker, recommending that this regex pattern is pulled out of the inline code and placed instead it as a protected member of the class. This way, a subclass - like yours - could simply declare a new pattern, rather than "duplicating" so much of the parent code. But I'd have to look and test a bit more before I suggest that to them.]

Anyway, just a stab in the dark...

**Update: 2010-12-17**

I discovered that a bit more is required to make it work. You need to override the protected member `$_typeKeys` and the protected method `_normalizeType()` to deal with your new "Property" type.

Your extended class could look something like this:

```
class Kwis_View_Helper_HeadMeta extends Zend_View_Helper_HeadMeta
{
    protected $_typeKeys     = array('name', 'http-equiv', 'charset', 'property');

    public function __call($method, $args)
    {
        if (preg_match('/^(?P<action>set|(pre|ap)pend|offsetSet)(?P<type>Name|HttpEquiv|Property)$/', $method, $matches)) {
            $action = $matches['action'];
            $type   = $this->_normalizeType($matches['type']);
            $argc   = count($args);
            $index  = null;

            if ('offsetSet' == $action) {
                if (0 < $argc) {
                    $index = array_shift($args);
                    --$argc;
                }
            }

            if (2 > $argc) {
                require_once 'Zend/View/Exception.php';
                $e = new Zend_View_Exception('Too few arguments provided; requires key value, and content');
                $e->setView($this->view);
                throw $e;
            }

            if (3 > $argc) {
                $args[] = array();
            }

            $item  = $this->createData($type, $args[0], $args[1], $args[2]);

            if ('offsetSet' == $action) {
                return $this->offsetSet($index, $item);
            }

            $this->$action($item);
            return $this;
        }

        return parent::__call($method, $args);
    }

    protected function _normalizeType($type)
    {
        switch ($type) {
            case 'Property':
                return 'property';
            default:
                return parent::_normalizeType($type);
        }
    }
}
```

As observed previously, this could be so much shorter if the `preg_match()` pattern checked in `Zend_View_Helper_HeadMeta::__call()` was factored out into a protected member called something like `$_callPattern`. Then the extended class would not have to duplicate the bulk of the `__call()` method. It would only have to override the protected members `$_typeKeys` and `$_callPattern` and implement the protected method `_normalizeType()`, as shown above.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I agree that this should be file as an issue.

Comment: Thanks for the accept and for the encouragement to add it as a ZF issue. I'll head on over there and file. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you David for the update, that's what I ended up doing.

Comment: BTW: The `HeadMeta` view helper now has an `appendProperty()` method that does exactly what we wanted. See the comments from Chris at on the ZF-issue: http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-10839