# Zend Framework - adding meta tags with property not working

Tags: facebook, zend-framework, facebook-graph-api, meta-tags

I am trying to use the facebook share button for which I want to dynamically set the title, description and image using the meta tags

```
<meta property="og:title" content="title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="description" />
<meta property="og:image" content="thumbnail_image" />
```

This is the same question :
[Zend framework: Meta property integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457467/zend-framework-meta-property-integration)

I have tried doing what was suggested - but its not working
This is what I've implemented in my layout.phtml

```
<?php
$doctypeHelper = new Zend_View_Helper_Doctype();
$doctypeHelper->doctype('XHTML1_RDFA');
echo $this->doctype();
?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/">
<head>
<?php echo $this->headMeta();?>
</head>
```

Then in my views, I try setting the meta property as

```
<?php $this->headMeta()->setProperty('og:title', 'my article title');?>
```

But this code wont execute and i'm getting an error when the view is rendered - something along the lines of

```
Invalid value passed to set; please use setMeta()
C:\webserver\apache\htdocs\dezyre\trunk\library\Zend\View\Helper\HeadMeta.php(164): Zend_View_Helper_HeadMeta->set(Object(stdClass))
```

Any idea, whats wrong here
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a hidden treasure in the view helper in the _isValid() method

```
// <meta property= ... /> is only supported with doctype RDFa
```

Unfortunately the error message you'll get is only to "please use setMeta()". The follow either in your controller or view should fix this problem.

```
$this->view->doctype('XHTML1_RDFA');  // controller
$this->doctype('XHTML1_RDFA');  // view
```

Comment: Just to add to this, I had a similar problem with `DOCTYPE HTML`, where when calling `setName($key, $value)` the `$value` was `null`